# How to repeat API call multiple times with delay depending on data received from server?

Tags: android

I faced the following problem: I need to call the REST API. If data received from the server is false, I need to wait 2 seconds and make API call again. If it's false again, I need to wait again 2 seconds and then call API. If it's false again, I should have one flow, if I received true in any of the responses, I should have another flow.

For this purpose, I created the following rx chain:

```
addDisposable(requests.checkPaylands3ds()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .doOnSubscribe { view.showLoading() }
                .repeatWhen { Flowable.timer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS).repeat() }
                .takeUntil { it.data.isCardExists }
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({
                    if (it.data.isCardExists) {
                        // received true flow
                    } else {
                        // received false flow
                    }
                }, this::onFailure))
```

But in such case, requests are repeated until I receive `true` and I need to limit it only 2 times additionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an int member of `class` called `counter`, initialized with 0 before sending the request and change `takeUntil` to:

```
.takeUntil( it.data.isCardExists || (++counter >= 2) )
```